# Double title bar on certain GNOME applications in Debian 10 / GNOME 3

Tags: debian, gnome3

See screencap of EOG below. This behavior is only occurring with GNOME applications such as EOG, Totem, and Gedit, though not all (such as GNOME Terminal).

[image: EOG]